# How can I read MongoDB data using discord.js?

Tags: database, mongodb, discord.js, bots

I've made a coin system and am trying to read how many coins the user has, but for some reason it's coming back as 'undefined', done anyone know why?

```
else if (command === 'coins') {
        const userData = await CoinSystem.find({userID : message.member.user.id});
        if (!userData.length) {
            const createdData = new CoinSystem({
                userID : message.member.user.id,
                userName : message.member.user.tag,
                coins : 0
            })
            await createdData.save().catch(e => console.log(e));
            await message.channel.send("You have 0 coins.");
            return;
        }
        if (userData.length) {
            await message.channel.send(await userData.find(coins));
        }
```

Creating the data.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const coinSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userID : {
        type : mongoose.SchemaTypes.String,
        required : true
    },

    userName : {
        type : mongoose.SchemaTypes.String,
        required : true
    },

    coins : {
        type : mongoose.SchemaTypes.Number,
        required : true,
        default : 0
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('CoinSystem', coinSchema)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, try using `await CoinSystem.findOne({userID : message.member.user.id});` instead of `await CoinSystem.find({userID : message.member.user.id});`

Second, try using `(!userData)` and `(userData)` instead of `(!userData.length)` and `(userData.length)`

Third, try using

```js
await message.channel.send({ content: `${userData.coins}`  });
```

instead of `await message.channel.send(await userData.find(coins));`

**The final code is:**

```js
const userData = await CoinSystem.findOne({userID : message.member.user.id});
  if (!userData) {
       const createdData = new CoinSystem({
       userID : message.member.user.id,
       userName : message.member.user.tag,
       coins : 0
   })
       await createdData.save().catch(e => console.log(e));
       await message.channel.send({ content: "You have 0 coins."});
       return;
   }
   if (userData) {
      await message.channel.send({ content: `You have ${userData.coins} coins`  });
   }
```

---

**Notes --> the reason of using:**

```js
message.channel.send({ content: `You have ${userData.coins} coins`  })
```

instead of:

```js
message.channel.send(`You have ${userData.coins} coins`)
```

is because of Discord.js v13.

If yours is discord.js v12, then u should use:

```js
message.channel.send(`You have ${userData.coins} coins`)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response, do you also know how I can get all data in a database? I'm trying to make an event system, where mods can set events which are added to a database. I'm trying to make an events command which lists all events, I know how to do everything apart from getting all the data. I tried EventDatabase.find() then tried to reference it as an array in a for loop, but it doesn't work.